# Evaluating limit involving integrals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits

I recently came across a challenging limit problem involving integrals of power functions during an examination, and I’m having trouble figuring out how to solve it. I would greatly appreciate any help or insights you can provide.

> The problem is to evaluate the following limits:
> $$
>  \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{\int_0^{1/2}x^{nx}dx}{\int_{1/2}^1x^{nx}dx},\quad \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{\int_0^{1}\frac{x^{nx}}{1+x^2}dx}{\int_{0}^1x^{nx}dx}.
> $$

I am aware that we might need to consider the function $f(x)=x^x=e^{x\ln x}$, which attains its maximum value of 1 at 0 and 1, and its minimum value at $e^{-1}$. However, I’m unsure how to utilize these facts to tackle the problem.

Any hints, suggestions or explanations on how to approach these types of limit problems would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Laplace's method might help, at least indrirectly.

Comment: What do you mean for Laplace's method?

Comment: The denominator is equal
$$ \int_0^{1/2}e^{n(1-x)\log(1-x)}\,dx$$ We have
$$\lim_{x\to 0} {(1-x)\log(1-x)\over x\log x}=\lim_{x\to 0} {\log(1-x)\over x\log x}=-\lim_{x\to 0}{{1\over 1-x}\over 1+\log x}=0$$  So it seems that the first ratio tends to $0.$

Comment: The basic idea behind Laplace's method is when you have a nice non-positive function $f$ with a unique root, then to obtain the asymptotics of $\int e^{nf(x)}\mathrm dx$ you can discard everything except a small ball around the root. There, you can approximate $f$ using Taylor to simplify the integrand.

Comment: I know this as the [method of stationary phase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_phase_approximation).

Answer (score 3):

@Matija provided solutions to both limits; however, it would be interesting to find their several first asymptotic terms at $n\to\infty$.

Let's take $a, b\,$ that $\,0<a<b\leqslant1$. For $n\to\infty$
$$\int_a^bx^{nx}dx\overset{x=e^{-t}}{=}\int_{\ln\frac1b}^{\ln\frac1a}e^{-nte^{-t}-t}dt=\frac1n\int_{n\ln\frac1b}^{n\ln\frac1a}e^{-xe^{-\frac xn}-\frac xn}dx\sim\frac1n\left(e^{-n\ln\frac1b}-e^{-n\ln\frac1a}\right)\tag{1}$$
If we put $b=1$
$$\int_a^1x^{nx}dx\sim\frac1n$$
More explicitly in the case of the first limit
$$\int_{1/2}^1x^{nx}dx=\frac1n\int_0^{n\ln2}e^{-xe^{-\frac xn}-\frac xn}dx=\frac1n\int_0^{n\ln2}e^{-x(1-\frac xn+...)-\frac xn}dx$$
$$\sim\frac1n\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\left(1+\frac{x^2}n-\frac xn+...\right)dx=\frac1n+\frac1{n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)\tag{2}$$
We are not allowed to take $a=1$ in (1): the function $f(x)=x^{nx}$ is not analytical at $x=0$ and has the infinite derivative in this point.

Let's consider
$$\int_0^{1/2}x^{nx}dx=\int_2^\infty e^{-\frac{n\ln t}t}\frac{dt}{t^2}=\int_2^e e^{-\frac{n\ln t}t}\frac{dt}{t^2}+\int_e^\infty e^{-\frac{n\ln t}t}\frac{dt}{t^2}\tag{3}$$
where the first integral is exponentially small:
$$\int_2^e e^{-\frac{n\ln t}t}\frac{dt}{t^2}<e^{-\frac{n\ln2}2}\int_2^e\frac{dt}{t^2}=\frac{const}{2^{n/2}}\tag{4a}$$
We split the second integral into two parts:
$$\int_e^\infty e^{-\frac{n\ln t}t}\frac{dt}{t^2}=\int_e^{n/2} e^{-\frac{n\ln t}t}\frac{dt}{t^2}+\int_{n/2}^\infty e^{-\frac{n\ln t}t}\frac{dt}{t^2}$$
The function $g(t)=e^{-\frac{n\ln t}t}$ is monotonously growing on the interval $[e;\infty)$ ; therefore, we can estimate the first integral as
$$\int_e^{n/2} e^{-\frac{n\ln t}t}\frac{dt}{t^2}<e^{-\frac{n\ln (n/2)}{n/2}}\int_e^{n/2} \frac{dt}{t^2}=\frac1{en^2}=O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\tag{4b}$$
The second part is
$$\int_{n/2}^\infty e^{-\frac{n\ln t}t}\frac{dt}{t^2}\overset{t=nx}{=}\frac1n\int_{1/2}^\infty e^{-\frac{\ln n}x\big(1+\frac{\ln x}{\ln n}\big)}dx\overset{t=\frac1x}{=}\frac1n\int_0^2e^{-t\ln n\,\big(1-\frac{\ln t}{\ln n}\big)}dt$$
$$=\frac1{n\ln n}\int_0^{2\ln n}e^{-x\big(1-\frac{\ln\frac x{\ln n}}{\ln n}\big)}dx\sim\frac1{n\ln n}\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\left(1+\frac x{\ln n}\,\ln\frac x{\ln n}\right)dx$$
$$=\frac1{n\ln n}-\frac{\ln(\ln n)}{n\ln^2n}+\frac{1-\gamma}{n\ln^2n}+O\left(\frac{\ln^2(\ln n)}{n\ln^3n}\right)\tag{4c}$$
Putting (4a), 4(b), 4(c) into (3)
$$\int_0^{1/2}x^{nx}dx=\frac1{n\ln n}\left(1+O\Big(\frac{\ln(\ln n)}{\ln n}\Big)\right)\tag{5}$$
From (2) and (5) we get
$$\frac{\int_0^{1/2}x^{nx}dx}{\int_{1/2}^1x^{nx}dx}\sim\frac{\frac1{n\ln n}}{\frac1n}=\frac1{\ln n}\to 0\,\,\text{at}\,\,n\to\infty$$
Numeric check with WA confirms the first terms of the asymptotic.

For the second limit, considering continuous functions on the interval $[0;1]\,\,a(x),\, b(x)>0\,$
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\int_0^{1}x^{nx}a(x)dx}{\int_{0}^1x^{nx}b(x)dx}=\frac{a(1)}{b(1)}$$

Comment: Nice answer! (+1) For your last expression, do you not also need $a$, $b$ not vanishing as $x\to 1$ to avoid the leading term vanishing?

Comment: @Sal, thank you :) You are right - this condition is needed. Correcting

Comment: Small correction: I did determine the first order asymptotics of all numerators and denominators. I just avoided asymptotic equivalence and the Bachmann-Landau notation since I wasn't sure if the OP is familiar with it. And could you please prove the last statement? Thanks!

Comment: @Matija, thank you for your comment. I changed the wording regarding the asymptotics  - to be more correct. I also changed the condition imposed on the functions - to get it closer to the OP case and avoid additional investigations which, in my opinion, are not relevant to the case. The limit follows from the fact that we get the key asymptotic terms at $x\to1$, so only values at this point are relevant.

Answer (score 2):

I will provide separate answers for the two questions. (In future questions, feel free to post two separate questions as well, it also makes sense in terms of the rewarding system and in terms of transparency.) Here, I discuss the first ratio.

Let $f(x)=x\ln(x)$ and let $n$ be sufficiently large. Recall that $f(x)\ge x-1$, so we have
\begin{align*}
\int_{1/2}^{1}e^{nf(x)}\mathrm dx\ge\int_{1/2}^1e^{n(x-1)}\mathrm dx=\frac 1n(1-e^{-0.5n}).
\end{align*}
For the numerator let $c_n=1/\sqrt n$.
Recall that $f(x)\le f(c_n)$ for $c_n\le x\le 1/2$, so we have
$$\int_{c_n}^{1/2}e^{nf(x)}\mathrm dx\le\frac12 e^{nf(c_n)}=\frac12e^{-f(\sqrt n)}\le\frac12e^{-\sqrt n+1}\le2e^{-\sqrt n}.$$
This shows that the denominator dominates the "remainder" in the numerator. Now, let
$$m_n=\frac{f(c_n)}{c_n}=-\frac12\ln(n)$$
be the slope of the secant line $g_n(x)=m_nx$ through the origin $(0,f(0))$ and $(c_n,f(c_n))$. Recall that  $f(x)\le g_n(x)$ for $x\le c_n$. This yields
$$\int_0^{c_n}e^{nf(x)}\mathrm dx\le\int_0^{c_n}e^{nm_nx}\mathrm dx=\int_0^{c_n}e^{-0.5f(n)x}\mathrm dx=-\frac2{f(n)}\left(e^{-0.5f(n)c_n}-1\right)\le\frac 2{f(n)}.$$
This completes the discussion of both parts of the numerator and yields
\begin{align*}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\int_0^{1/2}e^{nf(x)}\mathrm dx}{\int_{1/2}^1e^{nf(x)}\mathrm dx}
&\le\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\frac2{f(n)}+2e^{-\sqrt n}}{\frac1n(1-e^{-0.5n})}
=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2n}{f(n)}\cdot\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1+f(n)e^{-\sqrt n}}{1-e^{-0.5n}}=0\cdot 1=0.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

For the second ratio, we recall from the first ratio that the dominant part is given by $x$ close to $1$. In this case $1+x^2$ is essentially $2$, so the limit should now be $\frac12$. This means that bounds don't suffice anymore, we need to determine the asymptotics of the numerator and the denominator. Let $f(x)=x\ln(x)$; $C_n=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ and let $n$ be sufficiently large. Recall from the other answer that
$$\int_0^{1/2}e^{nf(x)}\mathrm dx\le\frac2{f(n)}+2e^{-\sqrt n}.$$
But using $f(x)\le f(C_n)$ for $1/2\le x\le C_n$ further yields
$$\int_{1/2}^{C_n}e^{nf(x)}\mathrm dx\le\frac12e^{nf(C_n)}\le\frac12e^{-C_n\sqrt n}$$
using $\ln(x)\le x-1$. For the last part we use $x-1\le f(x)\le x-1+(x-1)^2=x(x-1)$ for $x\le 1$ (since $f(1-x)\le-x(1-x)$ using $\ln(x)\le x-1$). This shows that
\begin{align*}
\int_{C_n}^1e^{nf(x)}\mathrm dx&\ge\frac1n(1-e^{-\sqrt n}),\\
\int_{C_n}^1e^{nf(x)}\mathrm dx&\le\int_{C_n}^1e^{nx(x-1)}\mathrm dx
\le\int_{C_n}^1e^{C_nn(x-1)}\mathrm dx=\frac{1}{C_nn}(1-e^{-C_n\sqrt n}).
\end{align*}
Putting all three parts together and using a sandwich for the dominant contribution, this shows that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\int_0^1e^{nf(x)}\mathrm dx=1.$$
Using that $\frac{1}{1+x^2}e^{nf(x)}\le e^{nf(x)}$ gives bounds for the first two parts. But for the third part we have
$$\frac12\le\frac{1}{1+x^2}\le\frac{1}{1+C_n^2}=\frac12\cdot\frac1{1-\frac1{\sqrt n}+\frac1n}.$$
Combining this with the argument above for the dominant part (add $\frac1{1+x^2}$ and use the appropriate bound, e.g. $\frac 12$ for the lower bound) gives
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}2n\int_0^1\frac{e^{nf(x)}}{1+x^2}\mathrm dx=1.$$
Combining the asymptotics of the numerator and denominator gives
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\int_0^1\frac{e^{nf(x)}}{1+x^2}\mathrm dx}{\int_0^1e^{nf(x)}\mathrm dx}=\frac12\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2n\int_0^1\frac{e^{nf(x)}}{1+x^2}\mathrm dx}{n\int_0^1e^{nf(x)}\mathrm dx}=\frac12.$$